# How to use custom Android.mk with new gradle build system

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, ndk-build

I know how use custom `Android.mk` with old gradle:

```
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jni'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        commandLine '/.../android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
```

It's not working with new gradle: `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0` :

```
Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig_Impl
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with the new gradle-experimental plugin, your configuration would be:

```
model {
    //...
    android.sources{
        main.jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/none']
            }
        }
        main.jniLibs {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine '/.../android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

Note that version 0.3.0-alpha7 of the gradle-experimental plugin is out.

Comment: Okey, and what's about `Application.mk`? For example i have flags `APP_CFLAGS += -DSTDC_HEADERS`
`APP_PLATFORM := android-23`

Comment: the snippet I put is to make the new plugin work like the former one for you, by keeping your Makefiles and calling ndk-build. If you want to migrate to a full gradle solution, it's a different question, you can look at my tutorial here: http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/

Comment: I don't suppose anyone knows how to do this with gradle-experimental 0.6.0-alpha5? Trying to set the source dirs gives me an error "Attempt to read a write only view...".

Comment: can you try `srcDirs.removeAll() ; srcDirs.add()` ? I haven't tested it yet, but if it works, I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: "ndLine '/.../"...Why do you have three periods there?

Comment: the ... is a placeholder you should replace with the absolute path to your ndk install

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your build.gradle file. This will cause the `ndk-build` to run as part of project build using the specified .mk file.

```
android{
     externalNativeBuild {
         ndkBuild {
             path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous response:
With Experimental Plugin version 0.7.0-alpha1 this works on Windows

```
model {

    // ...

    android.sources.main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/none']
            }
        }
        jniLibs {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    def cmdline = "${System.env.ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/ndk-build -C \"" + file('src/main').absolutePath + "\" > ndk-build-log.txt 2>&1"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', cmdline
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```