# Making an Android Studio JNI static lib to be read by JNI

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

**Too less memory in HW phones and tablets, but HAXM works fine?**

My basic problem is that my app (most likely JNI dynamic library loaded by my Java app) is too large. The Java app crashes without calling the JNI instructions using HW phones and templates. However it works fine with the HAXM emulator that just enlarge the primary memory of itself.

I need to reduce the size of the JNI dynamic library, I assume.

**I have a huge number of C-functions, most of them not used?**

Covering an topic area of application programming, more than 64000 entries and 995 are used. Making a C-program in Win32 the linker filter the unused stuff away. Real smooth.

However in Android Studio I have as usual a Java app written using a dynamic JNI library, that is the Android JNI standard use. There is no linker determine what functions are used or not. However I have a front-end JNI file that calls the other bunch of C-functions. The Java system do not analyse what JNI functions are called and find the tree of calls being able to sort it out, I assume? (Nor would a DLL in WIn32 do because it don't know what will be called, I assume.)

**The static lib approach might work, how do I do it?**

One idea is to create a static lib of the huge number of C-functions and when the standard Android JNI uses it by calls from the front end JNI file, I assume that this will only use the functions of the static library needed and drop the rest, like when linking for the Win32 C-program. I might be wrong?

Well, I tried to find out how to do a static lib in the Android Studio, and also how to use a proprietary static lib to be linked into the JNI dynamic lib. However it is very hard to find out by googling or searching by stackoverflow. I assume this approach is rare.

- Does anyone know how to make a static JNI lib in Android Studio
- Does anyone know how to use a static JNI lib in Android Studio making a Android app with a
  JNI front-end calling the static lib functions?
- And is able to describe it?
- It might not be possible in the JNI and then it is good to know it is
  impossible. Is it possible to get this optimisation made this way?

Comment: Have you tried setting the default symbol visibility to `hidden` and garbage collecting unused code/data section? See https://blog.algolia.com/android-ndk-how-to-reduce-libs-size/

Comment: This question does not show any research effort -1 is unfair in my view. Look, the entire environment of Android studio NDK is changed by version 1.3 a few months ago, can't even see there is a android.mk file anymore but a build.gradle. The Android studio guide is not really fully updated and the NDK pages not at all. Even if not, running NDK as separate installations, static lib issues are very rare in stckoverflow. Information about android/gradle linker optimisation, tell me where to find it?

Comment: If you want to use you're own Android.mk while building with Gradle, there are several question about how to do that already. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970094/how-to-use-custom-android-mk-with-new-gradle-build-system

Comment: @Michael, now we are talking about the right theme, and a good thread to investigate deeper and test. Looks like there are built in optimisations if they are just switched on (why they aren't by default is an enigma. Still they are dealing with android.mk and ap.mk scripts but might be convertible to AS1.3+ gradle. Let's see what comes out of it?

Comment: Yes @Michael, in the app build gradle there is an interesting section:
   android.ndk {
        moduleName = "AndroidRosetta"
        /*
         * Other ndk flags configurable here are
         * cppFlags += "-fno-rtti"
         * cppFlags += "-fno-exceptions"
         * ldLibs    = ["android", "log"]
         * stl       = "system"
         */
    }
Wonder where the documentation of that is. I will make a search of it. (There looks to be a number of linker/compiler flags to possibly be set. Just what I was looking for.)

Comment: Well I tried with the
CFlags.add("-ffunction-sections")
CFlags.add("-fdata-sections")
CFlags.add("-fvisibility=hidden")
ldFlags.add("-Wl,--gc-sections")
And there was no change, still my Samsung T3 crashes I assume on System.loadLibrary("AndroidRosetta"); (works before and crashes after the first method of the java code I can put a breakpoint. I assume this is due to a too large library and too less memory in the T3. But I don't know. Is there are chance to measure the size of the JNI dynamic library and how much memory there actually is? Thing is the app works in HAXM but no HW unit I have.

Comment: The amazing thing is that with the optimisation flags the apk is 6,39Mb and without 2,193Mb, should be the other way around? Looks like I have to do some serious reading?? Still crashing in HW units and running well in HAXM.

Comment: 2MB cannot be too much. Hopefully system logs indicate the crash and its cause.

Comment: Are you building for x86 only (as indicated by you using the HAXM emulator), or for all architectures? Do you test it on an x86 device, or ARM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static library in Android Studio, but you should build it with **ndk-build** using **Android.mk** as configuration.

In your build.gradle you can refer to this prebuilt library "c:\android\obj\libmystatic.a":

```
model {
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
        abiFilters += armeabi-v7a
        ldFlags += "-LC:/android/obj"
        ldLibs += "mystatic"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is how to disguard unused functions in a JNI file**

Well I answer my own question with the help of @Michaels hint.

The basic problem is a too huge APK for the HW Samsung Tab3 so it crashes, while the HAXM works fine. Using a small JNI dummy I initially made works in the Tab3 but not the real JNI code. My assumption is it is too large, well is it?

The idea of making a static lib using it when making the dynamic automatic JNI lib is redundant if the optimisations are available in other ways. The horror is to manually sort out what is used among more than 64K entries. Thanks in anyway @Alex.

Yes there are optimisations possible by setting the following flags in the app gradle:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "XXXX"
    cppFlags.add("-ffunction-sections")
    cppFlags.add("-fdata-sections")
    cppFlags.add("-fvisibility=hidden")
    CFlags.add("-ffunction-sections")
    CFlags.add("-fdata-sections")
    CFlags.add("-fvisibility=hidden")
    ldFlags.add("-Wl,--gc-sections")
    /*
     * Other ndk flags configurable here are
     * cppFlags += "-fno-rtti"
     * cppFlags += "-fno-exceptions"
     * ldLibs    = ["android", "log"]
     * stl       = "system"
     */
}
```

This reduces my APK from 11Mb to 7Mb (removing the unused functions in the JNI part). And some changes in the app, reducing the Win64 app from 0,9Mb to 0,6Mb, reducing the APK to 6Mb. Setting the Build variant to arm7 debug (Tab3) the APK is 2,7MB but still crashes (on the load jni library command in the Main java).

**How do I know the release size? - Is it possible to test?**

The issue is how large the APK will be in release mode (I have the assumption it is smaller than debug mode) but release versions must be signed etc and my intension is not releasing the app for market but testing the size of it, see if the planned app possibly can fit in a commercial Android HW unit. If not I have to make a general redesign of my planned app, however being much wiser. But redesigning is a huge work and I rather like to be certain the original plan was impossible? Seeing apps like MS Office copies I assumed it must be possible.

Being trying to fiddle with the Build/Edit flavours the Gradle just complains putting away the debugging capabilities, so that was a dead end.

So the present question is:

**Is there any possibility to find out and try the app in release shape without commercially releasing it?**

Comment: New questions should be posted as questions, not as answers.

Comment: I found out I was wrong about why my app crashes in the ARM7 HW units and not in the HAXM (was not a memory issue). It was due to a problem with stdlib atof (changed it to strtod and it loads) that made the collapse loading th JNI library. See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73725). I have some other different problem with the ARM7 JNI, now. 
However I am still interested in the question "Is there any possibility to find out and try the app in release shape without commercially releasing it? "

Comment: ..which is a new question and therefore should be posted as such.