# Importing Android System app into Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Let's say I want to develop some system apps and contribute to AOSP.

Lets take the Music app, for example:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/platform/packages/apps/Music

I clone the Repo from Gerrit, and there is no sight of any Gradle files to be used with IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio, just a Android.mk file.

How do I compile and test the app?
How do I import the app into some IDE?
How do I debug the app?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own gradle project and declare `Android.mk` in it as mentioned in "[How to use custom `Android.mk` with new gradle build system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40028550/6309)" by [notsopopularguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2441299/notsopopularguy)

> Add this to your `build.gradle file`. This will cause the `ndk-build` to run as part of project build using the specified `.mk` file.

```
android{
     externalNativeBuild {
         ndkBuild {
             path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
         }
     }
}
```

This is also what is officially documented in "[Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle)", section "[Link Gradle to your native library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle) "

This